# PHP paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal, sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am using paypal sandbox for my transactions but ipn is not working. When i check ipn history in my sandbox account it often shows the status as "**Retrying**". Sometimes it show the status as "**Failed**".

When i try to resend the ipn again from the account it is successfully sent.

Can any one guide me in understanding why it sometimes fails and what the reason(s) could be?...

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't.
When it's 'Retrying' it means it did not get a proper HTTP/1.1 200 OK response from your script.
Most likely, this means it errorred out when attempting to POST data to it.
If you click on the 'Message ID' in the IPN history, you can view the HTTP status it encountered when accessing the script.

Once you've narrowed it down to a specific HTTP error code, you'd want to review your webserver access and error logs to find the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.

My problem has been resolved. The return url was incorrect, and that's why ipn was not working.

My return url was correct in the paypal account and that is why ipn was working from the account.